# How connect C# to Postgresql in host j.layershift.co.uk

Tags: c#, postgresql, connect, jelastic

I have installed postgresql database in http://postgres-project-1241043.j.layershift.co.uk/ host.

I want to connect to the database using C#. I use Npgsql with following connection string.

```
connectionString = @ "Server = postgres-project-1241043.j.layershift.co.uk, Port = 5432, User Id = postgre; Password = abcdef; Database = dbluanvantn;";
```

But I am not able to connect to the server and get error:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: Failed to a connection to
>   'postgres-project1241043.j.layershift.co.uk'.

Am I using correct connection string?. Help me fix it.

Comment: Are you able to connect using anything else from the same host?  Any kind of database management tool?

Comment: I connect database with geoserver host

Answer (score 0):

You can only connect to Postgres (on our Jelastic service) if you add a public IP to the node first. Without that step, you can only connect to it locally (i.e. from another server within your Jelastic environment).

Also I want to mention that you are always welcome to [contact our support team](https://www.layershift.com/support/?form=technical) (our tech. support is 24x7 and completely free; even for our trial accounts) if you need any further help.